# How to bind checkbox in angular with DB MeanStack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-xeditable

[image]hi all i work with angularjs ng-repeat .i want to bind checkbox based on db value true or false.but checkbox will not check/uncheck whether db value is true?

```
 serverjs// app.get('/contactdetail', function (req, res) {
console.log('I received a GET request');




db.contactdetail.find (function (err,docs) {

    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);

});});


controller var refresh = function () {
    $http.get('/contactdetail').success(function (response) {

        console.log('I received a GET request');
        $scope.contactdetail = response;

    });


};refresh();


  <tr ng-repeat="contacts in contactdetail><span  editable-checkbox="contacts.Number" e-name="Number" e-form="rowform" onaftersave="Dhkclick(contacts._id,contacts.Number)">{{ contacts.Number|| 'empty' }}
                                    </span></tr>
```

Comment: what is the response from db of `contacts.Active`

Comment: its true or false value @nivas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove e-name and e-form attirbutes in the editable-checkbox and bind the checkbox ngmodel with data from db and it will worked. For eg:

```
<span editable-checkbox="contacts.Number" onaftersave="Dhkclick(contacts._id,contacts.Number)">
{{ contacts.Number|| 'empty' }}
```

**Update**

Please make sure contacts.Number is boolean, if it is a string convert it to the boolean first

```
angular.forEach($scope.contactdetail, function (v) {
      if (v.Number === 'true') {
         v.Number = true;
      } else if (v.Number === 'false') {
         v.Number = false;
      }
  });
```

Update JsFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/ts3LxjLc/9/

Comment: it's hard coded means works fine i get value from DB but it's won't checked kindly verify@digit

Comment: It's not the checkbox issue, it's data from db issue. Please check that the value from db is a boolean and not a string.

Comment: hi @digit i edit mu post now check it's contain any mistake

Comment: contacts.Number is a string value. Convert it to boolean. I'll update my answer

Comment: it's work's and correctly.
i need when page load directly shows checkbox checked/unchecked .not show true or false

Comment: Hi @jose,  i think there's no options to show the checkbox directly. That's what editable-checkbox designed for. However, you can use the input type checkbox for that purpose instead of using this library. Thanks.;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758399/how-to-do-html-cell-edit-in-angular-js-mean-stack-with-mongo-db

@digit.