# How to edit an HTML cell in AngularJS with X-editable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-xeditable

I am using angular js ng-repeat to bind data and I need batch edit (xeditable) now when I click edit button whole table will convert into editable but I want where user want to edit that particular cell will change into editable
help
[image]
refer: https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table

Comment: No code, no help.

Comment: @Ankh i Mention link .

Comment: @jose Asumo que hablas español. Que es exactamente lo que necesitas? Que toda la tabla se convierta en editable o que solo la celda en la que esta el usuario se convierta en editable? // I am assuming you speak Spanish. What do you need? The current cell or the complete table to become editable?

Comment: kindly refer my link@sfratini that reference when we click edit button whole table to be in editable but i want user directly click what cell they want to be edit that particular cell only change into editable
http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/78/

Comment: current cell @sfratini

Comment: The title mentioned technologies irrelevant to the question. Also some grammer updates.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may want to enable editing each row with a button like in this example:

https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row

The example looks like it is creating a form for each row whereas you have only one form for the whole table.

If you do create a form for each row then you could also probably work out how to reference each row form and and trigger editing any way you want.